# LibGdx Scaling textures issue

Tags: android, libgdx, textures

I am developing a simple game and faced with a problem. I need to scale down my textures on small screen resolution devices, so I use filters:

```
Mytexture.setFilter(Texture.TextureFilter.MipMapLinearLinear, Texture.TextureFilter.Linear);
```

And the problem is that some textures are drawing normally, but something goes wrong with other textures:

[image]

When I use (Linear, Linear) filter everything is normal, but quality is disgusting.
Can anyone help me? Thanks in advance!

Comment: That doesn't *seem* to be a filter related problem. You should provided more code, like how are you drawing those textures for example, and if they are stored in an atlas, or standalone, or whatever...

Comment: Should not be a filter related problem, but `filterMin: MipMapLinearNearest` and `filterMag: Linear` worked best for my textures.